# Bug, css: Cut-off letters on review list

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The bottom edges of the title are getting cut off. This is in the review queue.

[image]

Comment: Yup. They sure are.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed, will be live after our next production build.